# How to add 24 rows under each row in Python Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Original dataframe:

a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6

New dataframe:

a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
(1st empty row)
(2nd empty row)
...
(24th empty row)
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6
(1st empty row)
(2nd empty row)
...
(24th empty row)

The question is: How to perform the transformation above? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
1  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
```

First multiple index values by number of repeated values and then use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with `np.arange`:

```
N = 5
df.index = df.index * (N + 1)
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.max() + N + 1))
print (df)
      0    1    2    3    4    5
0    a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6    b1   b2   b3   b4   b5   b6
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
    0  1   2   3   4  5
0  a1  2  a3  a4  a5  6
1  b1  2  b3  b4  b5  6
```

---

```
N = 5
df.index = df.index * (N + 1)
df = df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.max() + N + 1))
print (df)
      0    1    2    3    4    5
0    a1  2.0   a3   a4   a5  6.0
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6    b1  2.0   b3   b4   b5  6.0
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
def convert_int_with_NaNs(x):
    try:
        return x.astype('Int64')
    except Exception:
        return x

df = df.apply(convert_int_with_NaNs)
print (df)
      0    1    2    3    4    5
0    a1    2   a3   a4   a5    6
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6    b1    2   b3   b4   b5    6
7   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works but all the integral inputs become values with 1 decimal place. How to solve this problem?

Comment: @CharlesYeung - All values in columns are integers in original data?

Comment: some of them are integers

Comment: @Charles since you're introducing `NaN` values into columns now, then the other numeric values in that column have to be `float`s - they can't be `int`s anymore...

Comment: @CharlesYeung - It is possible in pandas `0.24+` with [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

Comment: @jezrael nice... Didn't realise about `Int64`... could certainly make use of that in future, but I think I'll wait until it doesn't come with the "experimental" banner on it :)

Comment: @JonClements - yes, it was really long wating feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order to add an empty row you can use the following insctruction :

```py
your_dataframe = your_dataframe.append({} , ignore_index=True)
```

To perform the requested transformation, as i don't know how your data is shaped, nor how it is indexed, i suggest you create a new empty dataframe.

For each of your initial dataframe entries, you should insert it to your new one, and append 24 time an empty row as i described.

Here is an example on how to perform it :

```py
## Use your own data instead
data = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6'],['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6']]
### Load the data in the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

## Create the empty dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

## Use the initial dataframe length to perform the row iteration
length = len(df.index)

## For each rows of the initial dataframe
for i in range(0, length):
    ## Append the current row to the new dataframe
    df2 = df2.append(df[i:i+1],ignore_index=True) 
    ## Adding 24 empty rows
    for j in range(0,25):
        df2 = df2.append({},ignore_index=True)
```

So if your initial dataframe is something like :

```py
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  a1  a2  a3  a4  a5  a6
1  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6
```

Once you have executed the script it outputs :

```py
      0    1    2    3    4    5
0    a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
...
25  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
26   b1   b2   b3   b4   b5   b6
27  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
...
49  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
50  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
51  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: As i said, the given istruction allows to add an empty row to - the end - of the data frame. To perform the requested actions, he can use this instruction in the way i described : Create a new dataframe, iterate on the original one, and for each found entries, append the entry to the new dataframe and append 24 empty entries.

Not the most classy, nor the most efficient, but it works.

Comment: @jezrael Updated the answer as requested. Hope it is clearer now.